# An accessible example of a preorder that is neither symmetric nor antisymmetric

Tags: relations, order-theory

For a project I am working on, I need an example of a preorder (reflexive and transitive relation) that is neither symmetric (like an equivalence relation) nor antisymmetric (like less than or equal to), preferably a non-mathematical example, or at least one that is accessible to non-mathematicians.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Order people alphabetically by name. This is reflexive and transitive but obviously not symmetric. It's not anti-symmetric either, because people can have the same name without being the same person (as anyone unlucky enough to have the same name as someone placed on a no-fly list can tell you).

Comment: I am not clear exactly what relation you have in mind. It's not something like "name alphabetically precedes", because that wouldn't be reflexive. So something like "name alphabetically precedes or is equal to"?

Comment: Yes, I meant "name alphabetically precedes or is equal to", @libcub. The point is that if $Y$ is partially ordered and $f : X \to Y$ is any function, you can define a relation on $X$ by saying $x_1 \le x_2 \iff f(x_1) \le f(x_2)$. This relation is always reflexive and transitive, and is usually not symmetric. And is not antisymmetric if $f$ fails to be injective. People having the same name was the first example of non-injectivity that came to mind, but you can easily make lots of examples this way.